# How can I insert data to my collection on my server-side main.js with meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, meteor

I am new with the meteor trying to modify the tutorial codes, I have a code listening packets on my server-side main.js. I also need to insert the data printed on the console to my database collection.

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import '/imports/api/tasks';
import { createServer } from "net";
import { Tasks } from "../imports/api/tasks"

Meteor.startup(() => {

  const server = createServer(socket => {
    socket.write("SEND OK")
    socket.on("data", data => {
      const text = data.toString();
      console.log(text);
    })
  })

  server.listen(8080)

});
```

Here is the code for my database in my imports/API folder. I couldn't manage to insert with the meteor methods. What is the proper way to do it?

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';

export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');

Meteor.methods({
  'tasks.insert'(text) {
    check(text, String);

    Tasks.insert({
      text,
      createdAt: new Date,
      owner: this.userId,
      username: Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).username
    })
  },

  'tasks.remove'(taskId) {
    check(taskId, String);

    const task = Tasks.findOne(taskId);

    Tasks.remove(taskId);
  },

});

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('tasks', function() {
    return Tasks.find({
      
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: Most everything looks ok, but I'm a little confused as to why it's necessary to create a new socket server when meteor already does this for you. Since you create your own socket, none of the code that you execute will run within a fiber or have access to the Meteor environment.

Comment: Also.. All of the Meteor methods that you have created are easily called from the client via `Meteor.call`. You should only have an issue with calling them if you are connecting from another server or app, and then I would definitely recommend using a DDP lib to simplify connecting to your Meteor app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method definition looks good and should work (including the insertion into the collection). But you don't need a method to do server-side functions. Since your socket server seems to run on the server as well (as it should), you can just insert into the collection directly from there. For instance:

```
  const server = createServer(Meteor.bindEnvironment(socket => {
    socket.write("SEND OK")
    socket.on("data", Meteor.bindEnvironment(data => {
      const text = data.toString();
      console.log(text);
      Tasks.insert({
        text,
        createdAt: new Date
      })
    }))
  }))
```

Of course, since that is running on the server, there is no concept of "current user" for these insertions. How do you know for whom the received data is? Is that part of the data coming on the socket? Once you know that you can add code to add that as `owner` and `username` as you had in your method definition, which is the schema I assume you want.

---

PS: updated based on error mentioned in the comments

Comment: I tried the exact same code now, but I got the same error after the packet received and printed on the console. ` I20200824-20:33:59.194(3)? This is a test package
W20200824-20:33:59.377(3)? (STDERR) packages\meteor.js:1186
W20200824-20:33:59.389(3)? (STDERR)     throw new Error("Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. " +
W20200824-20:33:59.393(3)? (STDERR)     ^
W20200824-20:33:59.466(3)? (STDERR) 
W20200824-20:33:59.475(3)? (STDERR) Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment. `

Comment: oh that's the error you ran into! You hadn't mentioned that yet. Right, yes, you need to wrap the callbacks using `bindEnvironment`. I updated the answer.

Comment: That worked thanks a lot, I am trying get used to ask questions here, sorry for that and thanks for the warning 